# i have mingw64 in my PATH but still not recognised

Tags: c++, windows, path, mingw

i have just followed some troubleshooting steps and have now got `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` in both my user PATH and system PATH but when i type `gcc --version` into a new command prompt window it still says that gcc is not a recognised command. any help?

Comment: Sometimes PATH is only updated after a reboot. If you want "now use" use `PATH=%PATH%;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` then press Enter, and then `gcc --version`

Comment: Try logging out then back in after you changed the windows `PATH` environment variable in the system settings.

Comment: Environment variables are only set when you start a program. So if you have changed your PATH you need to start a new terminal window for the new PATH to be recognised

Comment: Side note: Later in your programming career you may find yourself working on multiple projects with different versions of the same compiler. Putting the toolchain in the system path becomes a non-starter at that point. Even before that you may find  yourself in [DLL Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell) because some completely unrelated program's Standard Library DLLs are found before the ones that should go with the compiler or the other way around. Really weird errors can result.

Answer (score -3):

- C:\mysys64\mingw64\bin directory sometimes remains empty. So, when we run gcc --version, the system is not able to find the executable file.
  Try installing MinGW from here: https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_mingw/releases/download/13.2.0-16.0.6-11.0.1-msvcrt-r1/winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-13.2.0-llvm-16.0.6-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.1-r1.zip
- After downloading the zip file, extract it and copy the **mingw64** folder and paste it in **Local Disk C**. At last add **C:\mingw64\bin** to PATH variable.
  I hope this helps to solve your problem.
- This zip file contains latest MinGW-w64 UCRT Version 11.0.0 and GCC version 13.2.0

Comment: Added new link for MinGW-64.

Comment: I don't know why you're recommending such an old build. Also, MSYS2 is generally viewed as the best way to install mingw on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, I have updated the link , which now helps to download the  latest mingw-w64 version zip file. MSYS2 is a good way to install mingw, however, after installation the \mingw64\bin folder remains empty, and hence the system is unable to find the gcc executable file.

Comment: After installation of what? You install MSYS2, then use MSYS2 to install gcc. It's never not worked for me. And even if it didn't work, the solution is not to just drop binaries in MSYS2's directory. It would be to either fix MSYS2 or install a standalone version of minGW.

Comment: I first installed MSYS2 and then used it to install GCC. However, after installation the binaries folder for mingw64 was empty, so there is no binary executable for gcc. That is the reason I emphasized for standalone installation of MinGW using the WinLibs.

Comment: Maybe your antivirus was the problem. Or you had some other issue.